# Is it good practice to capitalize/not-capitalize a question's title?

Tags: support, title

Knowing that in some English texts, it is [common practice to capitalize words in titles](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/92083/2864), I want to know whether this is true for Stack Overflow et al, too.

**So my question is:**

Should I capitalize question headlines/titles?

Comment: Damn it! I've tried lots of different searches and completely missed these questions. Thanks, @Bart!